# snap polyline to road - google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am trying to realign the a lot of points (which forms a polyline for user trace) to the road.
The problem is that these are massive number of points, about 7000 point.

And the status is "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT".

my code is: http://snipt.org/APl0#expand

So how can I solve this problem. any Idea please ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something like [this‌](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrsB.html)​, combines the points as waypoints into fewer directions requests, however will still run into the query limit for hundreds of points. You will probably also run into issues with divided roads (if the point you provide is on the wrong side of the road, the resulting route will be non-optimal).

From one of my comments on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642959/limitations-of-snap-to-road-google-api-v3)

The only option I can think of to do this is to start with the end points, add waypoints as needed to follow the correct path, I don't know of a way to automate that (which doesn't mean it can't be automated).