# gmaps4rails snap markers to the road

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I would like to point on the map were tied to the nearest road and draw lines between them. Following the example of this: [polyline snap to road using google maps api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513360/polyline-snap-to-road-using-google-maps-api-v3)
The application uses a gem [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)

```
<div class="map_container" style='width: 800px; height: 500px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 500px;'></div>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null } });
      handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
        markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @markers.to_json %>);
        polyline = handler.addPolylines(<%=raw @polyline.to_json %>, { "strokeColor" : "#0088cc" });
        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();
      });
    });
</script>
```

At the moment I simply draw a line on a map connecting markers

Comment: Sorry I cant help these days but if you have a working version with standard google maps, the translation is direct.

Comment: how can I append markers(e.g. &markers=color:red|label:D|54.5661310,-1.2505580) to static map url?

Answer (score 0):

The day I tell I cant I finally can :)

I did translate your working solution in this plunkr, [click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2txIGCylRNi21PAhHdM4?p=preview).