# How to Add Snap to Roads Google Map in Android Studio

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, snapshot

Hello I would like to ask how to add Snap to Road when I have the route given by google map API.
I have a bunch of Lat lang from point A line to point B line and draw a lines like Polylines, but what i want is how to add this code snap to Road from given route?
this is how to add more points from the Point A to Point B,
here is what i want to add,
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

my project is look like this
[image]

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513360/polyline-snap-to-road-using-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: yes but i think its the same i already test the  snap to road but the points are giving the same point that i needed, so i think its useless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get overview_polyline by Json and Gson (should use https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=...&destination=place_id:...&mode=DRIVING&key=...)
2. Decode it to List by function

   ```
   public List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
   // encoded is overview_polyline.points; 
   List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
   int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
   int lat = 0, lng = 0;
   while (index < len) {
       int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
       do {
           b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
           result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
           shift += 5;
       } while (b >= 0x20);
       int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
       lat += dlat;

       shift = 0;
       result = 0;
       do {
           b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
           result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
           shift += 5;
       } while (b >= 0x20);
       int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
       lng += dlng;

       LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
               (((double) lng / 1E5)));
       poly.add(p);
   }
   return poly;
   }
   ```

   3.Add to map:

   ```
   PolylineOptions polylineOptions= new PolylineOptions();
   polylineOptions.addAll(decodePoly(overview_polyline.points));
   mGoogleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions.width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(false));
   ```

Comment: how to get encoded string? I am able to get the response as String....but not able get overview_polyline point ?