# Moving and showing the driving camera view on Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have added current location via google map routing with

```
        Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
            .travelMode(Routing.TravelMode.DRIVING)
            .key(getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_api))
            .withListener(this)
            .waypoints(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), site_location)
            .alternativeRoutes(false)
            .build();
    routing.execute();



   @Override
public void onRoutingSuccess(ArrayList<Route> route, int shortestRouteIndex) {

    if (polylines.size() > 0) {
        for (Polyline poly : polylines) {
            poly.remove();
        }
    }

    polylines = new ArrayList<>();
    //add route(s) to the map.
    for (int i = 0; i < route.size(); i++) {

        //In case of more than 5 alternative routes
        int colorIndex = i % COLORS.length;

        PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polyOptions.color(getResources().getColor(COLORS[colorIndex]));
        polyOptions.width(10 + i * 13);
        polyOptions.addAll(route.get(i).getPoints());
        Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polyOptions);
        polylines.add(polyline);

        int distance = route.get(i).getDistanceValue();
        if (distance < 1000){
            totalKm.setText( distance+" Metres");
        }else {
            totalKm.setText( (distance/1000) +" km");

        }
    }

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    builder.include(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()));
    builder.include(site_marker.getPosition());
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100);
    googleMap.animateCamera(cu);

}
```

THis displays a driving directions like

[image]

But am trying to display the default google map driving icon with zoomed view like

[image]

How do i proceed to add such a map while still retaining the polylines to show driving view.

Answer (score 9):

[Jinesh Francis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6295668/jinesh-francis) totally right in his answer: you should either run the default map Google Maps application through intent or modify the standard `MapView` (or `MapFragment`).

**TLDR;**

If you chose the second way - easiest approach is to use standard classes of Android Google Maps API to create view like in your example (other way is to create [`MapView`-based custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50591194/6950238)).

At first read carefully p 3.2.4 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services (d) of [Google Maps Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/):

> (d) No Re-Creating Google Products or Features. Customer will not use
>   the Services to create a product or service with features that are
>   substantially similar to or that re-create the features of another
>   Google product or service. Customer’s product or service must contain
>   substantial, independent value and features beyond the Google products
>   or services. For example, Customer will not: (i) re-distribute the
>   Google Maps Core Services or pass them off as if they were Customer’s
>   services; (ii) create a substitute of the Google Maps Core Services,
>   Google Maps, or Google Maps mobile apps, or their features; (iii) use
>   the Google Maps Core Services in a listings or directory service or to
>   create or augment an advertising product; (iv) combine data from the
>   Directions API, Geolocation API, and Maps SDK for Android to create
>   real-time navigation functionality substantially similar to the
>   functionality provided by the Google Maps for Android mobile app.

and if you not violate Terms of Service you can do what you want with that steps/tasks:

1) get user current location;

2) get a route path segment nearest to user current location (because user location rarely exactly on road);

3) get a azimuth (bearing) of this segment;

4) show map with route path and user current position marker with appropriate tilt and rotation according path segment bearing.

Task 1 can be solved like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591377/6950238) answer of [Axxiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053731/axxiss):

> ```
> private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
>         //your code here
>     }
> };
> ```

Task 2 can be solved via [`PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath()`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-) like in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950425/6950238):

> ```
> private LatLng getMarkerProjectionOnSegment(LatLng carPos, List<LatLng> segment, Projection projection) {
>     LatLng markerProjection = null;
>
>     Point carPosOnScreen = projection.toScreenLocation(carPos);
>     Point p1 = projection.toScreenLocation(segment.get(0));
>     Point p2 = projection.toScreenLocation(segment.get(1));
>     Point carPosOnSegment = new Point();
>
>     float denominator = (p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y);
>     // p1 and p2 are the same
>     if (Math.abs(denominator) <= 1E-10) {
>         markerProjection = segment.get(0);
>     } else {
>         float t = (carPosOnScreen.x * (p2.x - p1.x) - (p2.x - p1.x) * p1.x
>                 + carPosOnScreen.y * (p2.y - p1.y) - (p2.y - p1.y) * p1.y) / denominator;
>         carPosOnSegment.x = (int) (p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) * t);
>         carPosOnSegment.y = (int) (p1.y + (p2.y - p1.y) * t);
>         markerProjection = projection.fromScreenLocation(carPosOnSegment);
>     }    
>     return markerProjection;
> }
> ```

Task 3 can be solved with code like that:

```
private float getBearing(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
    double dLon = (end.longitude - begin.longitude);
    double x = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(dLon)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(end.latitude));
    double y = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(begin.latitude))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(end.latitude))
            - Math.sin(Math.toRadians(begin.latitude))*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(end.latitude)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(dLon));
    double bearing = Math.toDegrees((Math.atan2(x, y)));
    return (float) bearing;
}
```

where `begin` and `end` is begin and end of current route path segment.

Task 4 can be solved with code like that:

as marker you can use vector drawable of north oriented arrow like that:

[image: User location marker]

`ic_up_arrow_circle.xml` (also you can adjust transparency and colors):

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="93.934"
    android:viewportWidth="93.934"
    android:width="24dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#8fFF0000"
        android:pathData="m0,46.9666c0,25.939 21.028,46.967 46.967,46.967c25.939,-0 46.967,-21.028 46.967,-46.967c0,-25.939 -21.027,-46.967 -46.967,-46.967c-25.939,-0 -46.967,21.028 -46.967,46.967zM78.262,67.4396l-31.295,-16.845l-31.295,16.845l31.295,-51.614l31.295,51.614z"
    />

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M78.262,67.4396l-31.295,-16.845l-31.295,16.845l31.295,-51.614l31.295,51.614z"
        />
</vector>
```

and you can place it on map with code like that:

```
public Marker addDirectionMarker(LatLng latLng, float angle) {
    Drawable circleDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_up_arrow_in_circle);
    BitmapDescriptor markerIcon = getMarkerIconFromDrawable(circleDrawable, 150, 150);

    return mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
            .rotation(angle)
            .flat(true)
            .icon(markerIcon)
    );
}
```

where `150` is marker size in pixels. NB! You need `flat` marker for its rotation and tilt with map and `0.5f` for move marker anchor exactly on its center point.

then you can show all of this on map:

```
...
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(userPosition)
        .tilt(tilt)
        .zoom(zoom)
        .bearing(bearing)
        .build();
mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
...
```

But if you do only that marker of user current position appeared in the center of screen (because `GoogleMap.moveCamera()` sets the center exactly at `.target()`). So, to avoid it you need to shift down the map slightly - in that case user location marker should be appeared at the bottom of screen. For map center shift you need get current map center screen coordinates, then change `y` coordinate and get new screen center. Something like that:

```
...
LatLng mapCenter = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;
Projection projection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
Point centerPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(mapCenter);

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

centerPoint.y = centerPoint.y - (int) (displayHeight / 4.5);  // move center down for approx 22%

LatLng newCenterPoint = projection.fromScreenLocation(centerPoint);

mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newCenterPoint, zoom));
...
```

And with all of this stuff, for your route (with `zoom` = 15 and `tilt = 50`) you should get something like that:

[image: Directions view]

As you can see, the route path is not exactly on road, so you need to get route path points more precisely than Directions API response. You can get that e.g. via [Google Maps Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro) part [Snap to Road](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) which

> returns the best-fit road geometry for a given set of GPS coordinates.
>   This service takes up to 100 GPS points collected along a route, and
>   returns a similar set of data with the points snapped to the most
>   likely roads the vehicle was traveling along.

like in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47329553/6950238) answer. If your route path has more than points you need to split in into 100-points portions and process them separately (also Snap to Road API has 2500 request per day per user (IP) and 10 requests per sec. restriction).

And as [Jaswant Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10005707/jaswant-singh) answered you:

> need to set a custom marker (with icon same as that blue arrow) on
>   your current location and move it to the new location every time there
>   is onLocationChanged() callback is called (Also animate the camera to
>   that new location).

Also, you need to select `zoom` and `tilt` properties according, for example, current user speed: when user drives faster `tilt -> 0`. And so on. It's not a simple task.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, i see a major issue with the google policy on creating a realtime navigation by combining data from ....I have decided to shift my project to osrm by using leaflet map on a webview rather than google map.

Comment: @Geoff You're welcome! May be your project "contain substantial, independent value and features", but better - be careful.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko what an explanation!. I am able to reproduce all that, plus I am thinking of rotating the map on mobile rotation. I am able to get azimuth from sensors. I just need some help. Could you tell a way in which we can use the azimuth value of sensor to route's path segment azimuth as pointing forward?

Comment: @KaranJhinga If this answer is good - you can up-vote it. For you clarification please create separate question.

Comment: Thank you for your time on this complete answer :) That's sound very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jinesh’s answer,
If you still want to add that marker for development, you need to set a custom marker (with icon same as that blue arrow) on your current location and move it to the new location every time there is onLocationChanged() callback is called (Also animate the camera to that new location). 
And tilt the map a little to get the exact look of the google maps navigation view, though you won’t get to use all the functionalities but it’s worth to give it a try.