# snap markers to nearest polyline point Google Maps flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

I am writing a simple bus tracking app for my university shuttles. I have plotted out the bus GPS as navigation arrows along with the route on the map. Now as the actual GPS coordinate is a little of from the real location of bus than the plotted route, it is slightly off the road. Is there any way or method that I can call to snap these markers to the polyline nearest point in google maps flutter plugin? I just wanted to know if there is anything already in place that I am missing. I would be willing to write the custom nearest neighbor logic if necessary. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: As of now this is not possible using GoogleMapsFlutter

Comment: Thanks for the help @dm_tr

Comment: @AkashDeodhar did you manage to implement it? I'm facing the same problem right now!

Comment: @pa1nd sorry about the late reply. I adopted my marker GPS coordinate by writing custom logic to find nearest point on polyline from my wrong coordinate.

Comment: hey @AkashDeodhar, do you mind sharing your custom logic as a solution to this question? You can answer the question in stackoverflow, even if you are the author I think :)

Comment: Please, @AkashDeodhar share your custom logic

Comment: Hi, @AkashDeodhar I am facing same problem with my app can you please share your logic or code snippets ?

Answer (score 2):

I have done using `locationIndexOnPath`, `computeDistanceBetween`, `computeHeading`.

Step 1. add this function to get nearest polyline segment index based on you current location. pass your polyline coordinates list and current location. below function return index of given polyline coordinates list.

```
int getEdgeIndex(List<mt.LatLng> _coordinates, mt.LatLng currentLocation) {
    final int edgeIndex1 = mt.PolygonUtil.locationIndexOnPath(
        currentLocation, _coordinates, true,
        tolerance: 1);

    final int edgeIndex2 = mt.PolygonUtil.locationIndexOnPath(
        currentLocation, _coordinates, true,
        tolerance: 2);

    final int edgeIndex6 = mt.PolygonUtil.locationIndexOnPath(
        currentLocation, _coordinates, true,
        tolerance: 6);

    final int edgeIndex10 = mt.PolygonUtil.locationIndexOnPath(
        currentLocation, _coordinates, true,
        tolerance: 10);

    final int edgeIndex15 = mt.PolygonUtil.locationIndexOnPath(
        currentLocation, _coordinates, true,
        tolerance: 15);

    int finalIndex = -1;

    if (edgeIndex1 >= 0) {
      finalIndex = edgeIndex1;
    } else if (edgeIndex2 >= 0) {
      finalIndex = edgeIndex2;
    } else if (edgeIndex6 >= 0) {
      finalIndex = edgeIndex6;
    } else if (edgeIndex10 >= 0) {
      finalIndex = edgeIndex10;
    } else if (edgeIndex15 >= 0) {
      finalIndex = edgeIndex15;
    }

    print(
        "getEdgeIndex: index : $edgeIndex1, $edgeIndex2, $edgeIndex6, $edgeIndex10, $edgeIndex15, $finalIndex");
    return finalIndex;
  }
```

Step 2. Now add this function to get snap LatLag to snap you current marker in centre of polyline route.

```
Map<String, dynamic> getSnapLatLng(LatLng currentLocation) {
    final currentLocationMT =
        mt.LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);

    if (coordinatesMT.isEmpty) {
      for (LatLng latLng in coordinates) {
        coordinatesMT.add(mt.LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude));
      }
    }

    final int finalIndex = getEdgeIndex(coordinatesMT, currentLocationMT);

    if (finalIndex >= 0) {
      final snappedLatLng2 = (finalIndex < coordinatesMT.length - 1)
          ? coordinatesMT[finalIndex + 1]
          : currentLocationMT;
      final snappedLatLng = coordinatesMT[finalIndex];

      final distanceM2 = mt.SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(
          snappedLatLng, currentLocationMT);

      double heading = mt.SphericalUtil.computeHeading(
        snappedLatLng2,
        snappedLatLng,
      );

      final extrapolated =
          mt.SphericalUtil.computeOffset(snappedLatLng, -distanceM2, heading);

      print(
          "snapToPolyline:distanceM  $distanceM2, $heading, $finalIndex, ${coordinatesMT.length}");

      return {
        "index": finalIndex,
        "latLng": LatLng(extrapolated.latitude, extrapolated.longitude)
      };
    }

    return {"index": finalIndex, "latLng": currentLocation};
  }
```

NOTE: I have used https://pub.dev/packages/maps_toolkit this package for `locationIndexOnPath`, `computeDistanceBetween`, `computeHeading`.

Comment: Is it working still well? Why didn't you use the interpolate function in your solution?