# How to move a marker 100 meters with coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, geolocation, coordinates

I have 2 coordinates. Coordinate 1 is a 'person'. Coordinate 2 is a destination.

How do I move coordinate 1 100 meters closer to coordinate 2?

This would be used in a cron job, so only php and mysql included.

For example:

> Person is at: 51.26667, 3.45417
>
> Destination is: 51.575001, 4.83889

How would i calculate the new coordinates for Person to be 100 meters closer?

Comment: Are the coordinates in meters or is that lat/lon? If the latter, you have to do a coordinate projection into WGS84 or a simillar ellipsoid so you get coordinates in meters. Then, assuming you want to move 100 closer in a straight line (no streets or walls to consider) you can use the euclidian distance formula

Comment: those are lat,lng coordinates. Used by google maps

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use Haversine to calculate the difference between the two points in metres; then adjust the value of the person coordinates proportionally.

```
$radius = 6378100; // radius of earth in meters
$latDist = $lat - $lat2;
$lngDist = $lng - $lng2;
$latDistRad = deg2rad($latDist);
$lngDistRad = deg2rad($lngDist);
$sinLatD = sin($latDistRad);
$sinLngD = sin($lngDistRad);
$cosLat1 = cos(deg2rad($lat));
$cosLat2 = cos(deg2rad($lat2));
$a = ($sinLatD/2)*($sinLatD/2) + $cosLat1*$cosLat2*($sinLngD/2)*($sinLngD/2);
if($a<0) $a = -1*$a;
$c = 2*atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a));
$distance = $radius*$c;
```

Feeding your values of:

```
$lat = 51.26667;        //  Just South of Aardenburg in Belgium
$lng = 3.45417;
$lat2 = 51.575001;      //  To the East of Breda in Holland
$lng2 = 4.83889;
```

gives a result of 102059.82251083 metres, 102.06 kilometers

The ratio to adjust by is 100 / 102059.82251083 = 0.0009798174985988102859004569070625

```
$newLat = $lat + (($lat2 - $lat) * $ratio);
$newLng = $lng + (($lng2 - $lng) * $ratio);
```

Gives a new latitude of 51.266972108109 and longitude of 3.4555267728867

Comment: Following is a good supplement: http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Comment: Interesting, the Haversine. What would you use as R?

Comment: i know how to calculate the distance. But don't know how to adjust properly

Comment: @Vinko Depends how accurate you want the figure. I know it doesn't allow for polar flattening, but the radius figure in my code should be as accurate as most GPS systems

Comment: @Topener Haversine gives you a distance x between the two points. You want to move 100m, so you adjust the lat and long by a ratio of 100/x

Comment: i'm trying to use your function. but i get a rather large number. What would be the output of your function?

Answer (score 4):

If you understand JavaScript, you may want to check out the `moveTowards()` method in the following Stack Overflow post:

- [How to add markers on Google Maps polylines based on distance along the line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698112/how-to-add-markers-on-google-maps-polylines-based-on-distance-along-the-line/2701319#2701319)

This method returns the destination point when given a start point, an end point, and the distance to travel along that line. You can use point 1 as the starting point, point 2 as the end point, and a distance of 100 meters. It's written in JavaScript, but I'm sure it can be easily ported to PHP or MySQL.

You may also want to check out this other Stack Overflow post which implements a part of the above JavaScript implementation, as a user defined function for SQL Server 2008, called `func_MoveTowardsPoint`:

- [Moving a Point along a Path in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094268/moving-a-point-along-a-path-in-sql-server-2008/2124298#2124298)

The above uses SQL Server 2008's in-built `geography` data type. However you can easily use two `decimal` data types for latitude and longitude in place of the single `geography` data type.

Both the SQL Server and the JavaScript examples were based on implementations from Chris Veness's article [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Comment: Interesting postings and links

Answer (score 4):

Find the angle theta between the x-axis and the vector from person to destination.

`theta = Atan2(dest.y-person.y, dest.x-person.x).`

Now use theta and the amount you want to advance the point to calculate the new point.

`newPoint.x = advanceDistance * cos(theta) + person.x`

`newPoint.y = advanceDistance * sin(theta) + person.y`

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it does not consider the earth as a sphere... Degrees of latitude are parallel and are approximately 111km apart, but a degree of longitude is widest at the equator at 111km and gradually converges to zero at the poles.

Comment: I would still keep the answer here, because it is still relevant (to the title of the question at least)... You may simply want to put a note about this.