# All possible Lat and Lng in between to given Lat lng point

Tags: php, geolocation, latitude-longitude

How to get all possible Lat and Lng in between to given Lat lng in straight line and there will be a gap of at least 50 meter between two consecutive point using google API. If not then what will be best way to calculate it??

Please help me..

Comment: What do you mean there is at least 50 m between the points?

Comment: In a straight line, or along a great circle?

Comment: @mark it's straight line

Comment: @Andreas 50m means distance between two lat lng will be min 50 meter

Comment: Hi you can refer this post [Measuring the distance between two coordinates in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073281/how-to-move-a-marker-100-meters-with-coordinates)

Comment: @fKnight I can calculate distance but need to get all lat lng between two points